# How can I delay the call to a property in a list?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

One of the properties in a list take a long time to load (creates a thumbnail on the fly). How can I display the rest of the properties on a list and load the long processing one in the background.

The following example shows the situation. I'd like to be able to show the short name immediately and the long names as they become available.

```
public partial class MainWindow 
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var list = new List<Example> {
            new Example {ShortName = "A", LongName = "Z"}, 
            new Example {ShortName = "B", LongName = "ZZ"}, 
            new Example {ShortName = "C", LongName = "ZZZ"}};
        DataContext = list;
    }
}

public class Example : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String _shortName;
    public String ShortName
    {
        get { return _shortName; }
        set
        {
            if (_shortName == value) return;
            _shortName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ShortName");
        }
    }

    private String _longName;
    public String LongName
    {
        get
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return _longName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_longName == value) return;
            _longName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("LongName");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label>ShortName: </Label>
                        <Label Content="{Binding ShortName}" />
                        <Label> LongName:</Label>
                        <Label Content="{Binding LongName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Using the IsAsync as suggested meets your needs. "IF" your needs change to this i.e. instead of showing 2 labels you wanted to combine them into one label i.e. show the shortname, until the longname was loaded....then take a look at priority bindings.... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753174.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load the property asynchronously using the *[IsAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync.aspx)* binding property:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=LongName,IsAsync=true}" />
```

You can also use the *Fallback* property to display a message like *Loading* until the real value gets populated.